# What is $25^k$ + $5^k$

Tags: exponentiation

This is an extremely simple problem, but I can't find an example anywhere for some reason.

I know that $30^k$ is not correct

But I have no idea what else makes sense.

Comment: Hint:  $ \ 25^k \ = \ (5^2)^k \ = \ 5^{2k} \ = \ 5^{k \ \cdot \ 2} \ = \ (5^k)^2 \  $ .

Comment: "What is <some algebraic expression>" is a question that can't be answered without guesswork on our part. If you want help with simplifying or calculating an expression say so.

Comment: You're right, I just thought this could be further simplified, but I was incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about a simplified as you can get. You can also write it as $5^k(5^k+1)$. if you prefer that. There's no simple formula like $a^k$.